# SymPy expression containing function canceled by the inverse of the function

Tags: python, regex, sympy

```
from sympy import exp,log
import sympy as sym

x = sym.Symbol('x')

expr = log(exp(x))

print(expr)
print(sym.simplify(expr))

diff_expr = x - log(exp(x))
if diff_expr == 0:
    print('Expression was simplified!')
```

Apparently SymPy can not simplify expressions like these. Is there any way of doing this without having to handle it with string manipulations? I.e. something like this:

```
func_comb = ['exp(log(','cos(acos(','log(exp(','acos(cos(','sin(asin(']
# replace string expression with '' and remove surplus ')'
expr = str(expr)
for func in func_comb:
    if func in expr:
        expr = expr.replace(func,'')
```

Comment: Note that `x!=asin(sin(x))` most of the time since the sinus function is periodic.

Comment: Good point, I fixed it by adding another function.

Comment: *fixed it and added another function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, SymPy symbols are allowed to be complex numbers. For complex numbers, the relation `log(exp(x)) == x` is not true in general: for example, `log(exp(2*pi*I)) = 0`.

Avoid this by declaring the symbol to be real.

```
>>> x = sym.Symbol('x', real=True)
>>> log(exp(x))
x
```

For `asin(sin(x)) == x`, being real is not enough: for example, `asin(sin(2*pi)) = 0`. This relation is only true in a certain interval. Starting with SymPy 1.2, the function `simplify` allows you to force such simplifications with `inverse=True`; this flag makes SymPy assume that the expected "inverse" relations indeed hold for the provided inputs.

```
>>> sym.simplify(asin(sin(x)))
asin(sin(x))
>>> sym.simplify(asin(sin(x)), inverse=True)
x
```